# How to find the biggest word in a 2D array?

Tags: arrays, c, loops, multidimensional-array, string-length

I have an array that has a list of 15 different country names. I have to create a function that finds the largest name and returns its index, and if there are more then one that have a maximum length equivalent to each other it only has to return 1 of the indexes to the names. (Example below).

I'll admit and say I'm quite new to c. But have tried using the strlen(), and the strcmp() functions. I know I'm probably missing something huge here, but any help would be better then where I'm at now. Thanks in advance!

Here's what I thought would work:

```
int maxCountry(char countryNames[15][50]){

int i, x = 0, length, length2, returnVal;
char string[50], string2[50];
  
  for(i = 0; i < 15; i++){
      string = countryNames[i] ;
      length = strlen(string);
      string2 = countryNames[x];
      length2 = strlen(string2);
      
      if(length < length2){
        returnVal = x;
        x = i;
      }
  }

  return returnVal;
}
```

Comment: Don't think of `countryNames` as a "2D" array, but or as an array of strings.

Comment: And there's really no need to copy any of the string (which is *one* problem you have). You can get the length of the strings in `countryNames[i]` or `countryNames[x]` directly without the need to copy them.

Comment: You also have to think about the case when `if(length < length2)` is *never* true, what will the value of `returnVal` be then?

Comment: Define "largest name". Alphabetically, ASCII values, string length, what?

Comment: Welcome to SO. You forgot to tell us what your problem is. Where exactly are you stuck? Regarding `string = countryNames[i] ;`: You cannot assign anything to an array. Use `char *string;` instead of `char string[50];` Or better remove that variable completely as you do not use it anyway. You can use `strlen` directly with `countryNames[x]`

Answer (score 2):

I had trouble following your code's logic, I think it does a few operations that are not needed.

Here's my attempt at it, with the following obvious changes:

- Treat the array as an array of strings, not a 2d array.
- Pass in the number of strings.
- Return the index of the longest string, or -1 on error.

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int longest(const char **s, size_t n)
{
  size_t maxlen = 0;
  int maxpos = -1;

  for (size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i)
  {
    const size_t len = strlen(s[i]);
    if (len > maxlen)
    {
      maxlen = len;
      maxpos = (int) i;
    }
  }
  return maxpos;
}
 
int main(void)
{
  const char *s[] = { "foo", "hello", "you", "monster", "test" };
  printf("The longest is at %d\n", longest(s, sizeof s / sizeof *s));
  return 0;
}
```

This prints:

```
The longest is at 3
```

Comment: `const char **s` seems incompatible with `char countryNames[15][50]`

Comment: @DavidRanieri Yes, as pointed out in a comment above it's much better to treat it as an array of strings so that's what I did.

Comment: Yes, I have read it, but that may not be in line with the task of the OP.